# Sorting items in a dictionary when adding a new item rather than doing it after

Tags: c#, linq, enumeration

I am currently using the following code to sort a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, TKosStock> NewList = null;
if (SortBy.CompareTo(TSortOptions.sortASC | TSortOptions.sortPRICE) == 0)
   NewList = new Dictionary<string, StockObj>(this.StockItemList.OrderBy(n => n.Value.SellPriceRangeLowGross).ToDictionary(n => n.Key, n => n.Value));

this.StockItemList = new Dictionary<string, TKosStock>(NewList.ToDictionary(n => n.Key, n => n.Value));
```

This works well and re-shuffles my list correctly. I can then loop through `this.StockItemList` knowing my values are in the correct order.

**What I would like to do is add the items in the correct order in the first place.** I can't do this based on the SQL query because the prices aren't calculated when the SQL query initially runs.

p.s I assume the overhead for this re-shuffle is low but if it can be done when initially adding the items then I assume the overhead would be even lower.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want the data to be stored as sorted for display or for querying purposes?

Comment: Sorted for display but I am not binding it to any controls.

Comment: then perhaps use a `SortedDictionary` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using an ordered dictionary (non-generic):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx

Comment: I like the Linq method as it doesn't matter what order they are entered in. AFAIK, the OrderDictionary will order based on order inserted.

Comment: Pass an equality comparer into the constructor, no?

Comment: I will have a look into that. Thanks.